# Spark Cassandra Write Performance

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i am trying to load around 2 million records to cassandra through spark. Spark has 4 executors and cassandra has 4 nodes in the cluster. But it takes around 20 mins to save all the data to cassandra. Can anyone please help me to make this thing bit more faster.

Comment: This is only 1.6k writes per second, which is pretty slow for 4 nodes of C*. You need to specify a lot more information though if anyone is going to be able to help you. 
How are you reading the records
What code are you using for writing
What kind of hardware are the nodes
...

Comment: Actually i am using Dataframe to read the records and all the nodes have 7G memory storage

Comment: Can u please let me know generally what is the write speed for a 4 node cluster.

Comment: Without node details this is similar to asking, "what is the general speed of a vehicle?" I would expect if I had 4 nodes of modern specs I would see write speeds of something around ~100k/s

Comment: Whether can i add any parameters in the sparkconf to make it more faster??

Comment: Like partitioning or splitting up the jobs

Comment: And the hardware of each nodes would be 7GB RAM and 20GB disk memory

Comment: 7GB ram is woefully under provisioned for C* all by itself, running that and Spark at the same time would be not good. Are these even real machines or are they VMs? You really need to give more details on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: they are VMs and spark is not in the same machine. Spark is in different cluster which has 64GB RAM...Will that be an issue and should i have cassandra in the same machine as spark..Please suggest me the ideal RAM size as i am a newbie to spark and cassandra, i dont have much idea about this configuration

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I can see several issues with your configuration

1. Running Cassandra in VM for performance benchmark
2. Spark NOT co-located (so no data locality ...)

In general, installing Cassandra inside a virtual machine is **not** recommended for performance benchmark, this is an **anti-pattern**. So your slow insertion rate is normal, do not complain, you can't ask for better perf while using VM ...